# Creating a stub file on ext3, poor man's HSM in Amazon with EC2, EBS and S3 -

Tags: linux, file, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, stub

All -

I'm working on creating a poor mans hierarchical storage management solution for my file servers in Amazon. What I would like to do is move files from my file server in EC2 with an atime > 30 days to S3 and leave a stub file behind. When a user, using POSIX standard commands attempts to access the file in any way it would be copied back onto the host and them manipulated there, this operation should be transparent to the user, other than being slow. I am assuming that when a user accesses a stub file I can copy the full file over the stub file transparently to the user?

I'm using ext3 and I can't find any information on creating file system stub files, or if I could use a couple of lines of (python|bash) as the "path" to the actual file in S3.

My other option, also a good one (I think) is to mount a POSIX<-->S3 file system on the file server, S3QL [2] or S3FS [3] seem to be good choices. I still need to help with creating the stub files, but a least this way the stub file target is on a POSIX file system on the same server. I let S3QL or S3FS deal with the POSIX <--> S3 interface.

Maybe all I need is a good stub file HOWTO, but any help would be very much appreciated, thank you very, very much.

[1] http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/

[2] http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon

C